# Query 1 table with multiple criteria from different rows that are dependent upon each other

Tags: sql, oracle

```
ID      segment   Type    start date    end date      added date
----------------------------------------------------------------
12345   10        2222    20170101      20200101     20180901
12345   20        2222    20140101      20160101     20150901
12345   50        4444    20170301      20200101     20180901
12345   60        4444    20140101      20160101     20150901
56789    4        2222    20170101      20200101     20180901
56789    6        2222    20140101      20160101     20150901
56789   10        3333    20170301      20200101     20180901
56789   56        3333    20140101      20160101     20150901
56789    7        4444    20110301      20120101     20180901
56789   12        4444    20100101      20100301     20150901
```

I am having a hard time querying data in 1 table where I need an ID depending on data in a different row in the same table. I am new to Oracle SQL.

I will have the following:

- type
- added date

I need to know which ID and segment has type 2222 added on the 20180901 with a start date before 20180901. Also for this ID there is a type 4444 with a start date before 20180901 and after the start date of 2222 segment.

In this example it would only be the first line ID - 12345   Segment -10.

Since the following:

- The ID has a '2222' segment that has an added date that equals
- The ID has a '4444' with a start date between the above '2222' segment start date and added date.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Truly,

Wendy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't post your DDL `CREATE TABLE ...` SQL statements, so I can only guess on the exact table name and column names/types. The query you are looking for should be similar to:

```
select
    *
  from my_table t1
  where type = 2222
    and added_date = date '2018-09-01'
    and start_date < date '2018-09-01'
    and exists (
      select 1 from my_table t2
        where t2.id = t1.id
          and t2.type = 4444
          and t2.start_date < date '2018-09-01'
          and t2.start_date > t1.start_date
    )
```

Comment: This is helpful, thanks. The one thing that I would need to tweak is (and t2.start_date < date '2018-09-01') since the real table may have thousands of rows and I would not know the actual date. Would I use another "Exist" statement or would an "In" be quicker when there is a lot of data being processed? Thanks!

Comment: @RenBird In this example the dates are specified as literal values. Your query may use column values from other tables if you prefer; something like `t3.initial_date`.

Comment: Thank you. I am unable to give a vote or I would. I have been a member for many years but I am not on enough to what I should do when something is answered.